# How to set a datetimepicker automatically according to another datetimepicket VB.NET (Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on a library management project.
I have almost the complete project but I am facing a problem, when I issue a book to someone, I have to put a date of issue and a date of limit to return the book.
But on the date of the return book I want it to set automatically 2 months after the date of issue.
I do not have any code, all I have is 2 datetimepicker one for the issue and one for the return.
Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 
Code that I have tried till now:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker2.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(+2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: You said you don't have any code, you must have tried something? Catch an event of the first DateTimePicker when the value changes and set the value of the second one.

Comment: This site is not for teaching you the basics I'm afraid. If you have no code, it's too soon to be posting code. You need to think through the parts of the problem and attack each one separately: do something when the value in a `DateTimePicker` changes, get the value in a `DateTimePicker`, calculate a new `Date` value from an existing one, display a value in a `DateTimePicker`. Each one of those is pretty basic so you can research each one and make an effort to do each one, then put your partial solutions together. If you encounter a specific issue, THEN post all the info relevant to that.

Comment: Ok, so you are right, I have to have some kind of code right? And i get it. But I'm new here so I'm sorry if I am not so clear as day as you wish I would be. Anyways, I tried this:
I WILL ADD TO THE MAIN POST SOME CODE OF WHAT I HAVE TRIED.
But as you may know it doesnt work, aswell as I know that, maybe I am missing something so easy but if so please tell me what

Comment: A DateTimePicker.Value is not a string, so why do you convert it to one?  Formatting isn't important when dealing with date data.  Why change the value of Picker2 if the user is changing the value of Picker2?  I'm guessing you want to set the value of Picker2 when the user changes the value of Picker1?

Comment: @LarsTech Yes that's what i intend to to, I want the Picker2 to change for 2 months after the date that is set by the user in Picker1

Comment: Your changing "event" is wired to Picker2.  You want the code in the ValueChanged event of Picker1.

Answer (score 0):

It's that simple:

```
Private Sub AddTwoMonth()
    DateTimePicker1.Value = Today
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(2)
End Sub
```

Have fun.

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work, it simply does nothing. Thank you anyways for trying to help..

Comment: Try it on a button first. If it doesn't work when you click the button, there's something fishy going on.

After that you can build it on an event. Small steps!